# SSIS package shows vsjitdebugger on error

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging, ssis

I have an SSIS package which is launched by scheduler in command line via DTSExec with the following arguments:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /F "PackageName.dtsx" /Conf "Production.dtsConfig" /Set "\Package.Variables[User::ParamPromptForValues].Properties[Value]";"False"
```

Sometimes the package fails (in production) and launches vsjitdebugger which makes package execution to hang.

Question: How can I prevent package from showing vsjitdebugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something in your package is either (a) calling [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) or (b) throwing an unhandled exception. I've never run into this situation with any of the stock SSIS components, so I'd be suspicious of any custom-built or third-party components in the package.

[This MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/07/15/184490.aspx) suggests some possible registry tweaks.

Comment: It seems it was third party application (I have called from SSIS) which caused debugger to lauch. Thanks!